# SharePoint 2013 Discussions - Subscribing to Alerts on an Individual Post

Tags: alert, discussion-board

Believe I may have stumbled across a SharePoint qwirk, where users are unable to subscribe to alerts from an individual post. To note subscribing to alerts at the list level is fine (i.e. all items view)

I've validated the following steps on two separate environments, and received the same error.

- Create a Discussion Board
- Create a post in the Discussion Board
- Navigate back to the post
- Via the ... (next to the Reply / Edit links), select "Alert Me"
- On the alert subscription page leave all as default and click "OK"
- An error displays

The following error displays in debug mode:

> [ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId..ctor(String id) +607
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewContext.get_FolderContentTypeId() +459
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ViewSelectorMenu.AddMenuItems() +526 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ToolBarMenuButton.CreateChildControls()
>   +719    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ViewSelectorMenu.CreateChildControls()
>   +912    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +189    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TemplateBasedControl.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +132
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ToolBarMenuButton.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>   +49    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +95    System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +729 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.CreateChildControls()
>   +2990    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartMobileAdapter.CreateChildControls()
>   +129    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +166    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +73
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4090

Looking into why, I believe the JavaScript behind the alert on the discussion post page includes the "Source" parameter twice.

Does anyone know of a resolution / workaround to resolve?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any update on this?

Comment: I've opened a PSS case on this issue.